# MySQL Large Data table performace issues

Tags: mysql, subquery

i am facing big problem about SQL performance. Can anybody help me to fix this issue here is my problem

In Product_model Table i have **133,063,450 records** and in product_data table i have **43,34,550 Records**

I write this query

Select Product_Name from product_data where `autoopartoo_id` IN
(
    SELECT `autoopartoo_id` FROM `product_model` where make='IVECO' && model= 'DAILY I' && engine='Diesel'  && `start_yr` ='1992' )  && classid=216 limit 20

But this query too much time to load data .

please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query, written with a more standard SQL syntax:

```
Select Product_Name
from product_data
where autoopartoo_id IN (SELECT autoopartoo_id
                         FROM product_model
                         where make = 'IVECO' AND model = 'DAILY I' AND
                               engine = 'Diesel' AND start_yr = '1992'
                        ) and
      classid = 216
limit 20;
```

The best way to improve performance is by using indexes.  I would recommend the following two:

```
product_data(classid, autoopartoo_id, Product_Name)
product_model(make, model, anging, start_yr, autoopartoo_id)
```

There may be other steps you can take, but you don't mention the database and the particular software is important for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look at indexing your table.
I am not a mysql expert but you should put a nonclustered index over the 2 tables you are selecting from .
Mssql has a performance tuner which you can run  the query against and it will generate indexing statements for you. I would say mysql would have something similar.

Comment: "In most cases JOINs are faster than sub-queries and it is very rare for a sub-query to be faster.

In JOINs RDBMS can create an execution plan that is better for your query and can predict what data should be loaded to be processed and save time, unlike the sub-query where it will run all the queries and load all their data to do the processing.

The good thing in sub-queries is that they are more readable than JOINs: that's why most new SQL people prefer them; it is the easy way; but when it comes to performance, JOINS are better in most cases even though they are not hard to read too."

Comment: Hi     Select Product_Name from product_data where autoopartoo_id IN ( SELECT autoopartoo_id FROM product_model where make='IVECO' && model= 'DAILY I' && engine='Diesel' && start_yr ='1992' ) && classid=216 limit 20            Which join i must use to make query faster and also i put index on all above fields

Comment: Select p.product_name from product_data p inner join product_model m on p.autoopartoo_id = m.autoopartoo_id and m.make =